# For Loop: i in variable names

Tags: c#, variables, for-loop, names

```
SubnetConvert SubnetOctet1 = new SubnetConvert();
SubnetConvert SubnetOctet2 = new SubnetConvert();
SubnetConvert SubnetOctet3 = new SubnetConvert();
SubnetConvert SubnetOctet4 = new SubnetConvert();

    int Octet1 = int.Parse(txtOctet1.Text);
    SubnetOctet1.OctetConvert = Octet1;
    lblOctet1.Text = SubnetOctet1.SendBinary;

    int Octet2 = int.Parse(txtOctet2.Text);
    SubnetOctet2.OctetConvert = Octet2;
    lblOctet2.Text = SubnetOctet1.SendBinary;

    int Octet3 = int.Parse(txtOctet3.Text);
    SubnetOctet3.OctetConvert = Octet3;
    lblOctet3.Text = SubnetOctet1.SendBinary;

    int Octet4 = int.Parse(txtOctet4.Text);
    SubnetOctet4.OctetConvert = Octet4;
    lblOctet4.Text = SubnetOctet1.SendBinary;
```

is it possible to put all this code in a For loop like

```
For (int i = 1; i <=4; i++)
{
SubnetConvert SubnetOctet[i] = new SubnetConvert();

    int Octet[i] = int.Parse(txtOctet[i].Text);
    SubnetOctet[i].OctetConvert = Octet[i];
    lblOctet[i].Text = SubnetOctet[i].SendBinary;
}
```

I have tried the coding above and it doesn't work, I have just put it there for an example of what I want to achieve

Comment: Yes it is possibile. You have just to review some code and you can get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code sample is not something possible - there is no support for control arrays as you have  shown.

A better way would be to write a function that encapsulates the repeating code and pass in the differing parameters.

```
private void SetBinaryValue(string value, Label display)
{
    int Octet = int.Parse(value);
    SubnetOctet.OctetConvert = Octet;
    display.Text = SubnetOctet.SendBinary;
}
```

You would call this function like so:

```
SetBinaryValue(txtOctet1.Text, lblOctet1);
SetBinaryValue(txtOctet2.Text, lblOctet2);
```

Note that you only need one `SubnetConvert` with this approach (which you can either initialize within the function, or as a field).

Comment: +1 I started writing that up, but I think OP has further problems with the code inside the loop.

Comment: @Yuck - The array option is valid, but I don't like it for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to loop through named controls using `FindControl`:

```
var subnetOctet = new SubnetConvert();

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    // ID suffix as string
    var indexText = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // ID of TextBox and Label
    var textBoxId = "txtOctet" + indexText;
    var labelId = "lblOctet" + indexText;

    // The TextBox and the Label
    var textBox = (TextBox)FindControl(textBoxId);
    var label = (Label)FindControl(labelId);

    // Parse the value into an int
    int octet = int.Parse(textBox.Text);

    subnetOctet.OctetConvert = octet;

    // Update the TextBox's Test
    label.Text = subnetOctet.SendBinary;
}
```

One advantage to using this method is that you can add more controls on the fly, or even programmatically, and if you keep track of the number of subnets you need to handle, you do not have to update your code.

Answer (score -1):

You could also create an Array with the your objects as the elements and then loop through the array and execute the functions based on the array position at loop position;

```
Dog pet1 = new Dog();
        Dog pet2 = new Dog();
        Dog pet3 = new Dog();
        Dog pet4 = new Dog();

        //create a list of pets and add your pets to them
        List<Dog> pets = new List<Dog>();
        pets.Add(pet1);
        pets.Add(pet2); 
        pets.Add(pet3);
        pets.Add(pet4);


        //Using a for each loop to go through each element in the array and execute identical actions on each 
        //element
        foreach (Dog pet in pets)
        {
            pet.SetName("Fido");
        }

        //or create a for each loop that will allow you to know the position 
        //you are currenly at in the arry as the integer of i increments in the loop
        for (int i = 0; i <= pets.Count; i++)
        {
            pets[i].SetName("Fido");
        }
```

Ideally what you will want to do is create a single object and insert multiple instances of the object into the list via another loop and then use the foreach or the for loop to access an element of the list to manipulate a singular instance.

```
Dog dog = new Dog();

        //create a list of pets and add your pets to them
        List<Dog> pets = new List<Dog>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            pets.Add(dog);
        }

        //Using a for each loop to go through each element in the array and execute identical actions on each 
        //element
        foreach (Dog pet in pets)
        {
            pet.SetName("Fido");
        }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Would you mind adding a code snippet and/or explain what the problem with the displayed code is?